# I Can't locate SOAP.pm in @INC

Tags: macos, perl, soap

I'm writing this perl file to test it with my web service. Run this code through the command: `perl clientWSperl.pl`

But it appears to me:

```
Can not locate SOAP.pm in @INC ( May you need to install the SOAP module) ( @INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-th. BEGIN failed - compilation aborted at clientWSperl.pl line 2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. You can click this [edit] link that I conveniently placed in my comment. Comments with code are hard to read, and because I don't know where the linebreaks are I cannot do that for you. So here is the [edit] link again. Please click that [edit] link it and [edit] your question to make the [edit]ing [edit] yourself. :)

Comment: 'm writing this file perl to test it with my webservice .

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl - w
use SOAP ::Lite;
my $url = 'http://localhost:8883/hello?wsdl';
my $service = SOAP::Lite->service($url);
print "\nResultat : ", $service->ditBonjour('Objis');

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question and ***copy and paste*** your code into it. You have been asked several times already; what is your problem with revealing what you have written?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no space between `SOAP` and `::Lite`.

```
use SOAP::Lite;
```

Comment: when i write : use SOAP::Lite;

Comment: You should fix the error in the script, not in the command line.

Comment: http://objis.com/formation-java/tutoriel-web-services-clients-perl-ruby-java.html